# Unescape encoded string in Node (\x##)

Tags: node.js

I have the following encoded string in Node;

`const test = '\x50\x77\x6b\x6d\x77\x37\x54\x43\x6f\x51\x3d\x3d'`

I want to get it's unencoded value `Pwkmw7TCoQ==`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the .toString() method. It should work.

`test.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do there. Just print the string to the console as it is.

```js
const test = '\x50\x77\x6b\x6d\x77\x37\x54\x43\x6f\x51\x3d\x3d';
console.log(test);
```

`'\x50\x77\x6b\x6d\x77\x37\x54\x43\x6f\x51\x3d\x3d'` and `'Pwkmw7TCoQ=='` are different notations for the same value.